# How can I customize Devise error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

In my password change controller, I m allowing users to change their password provided they have valid password request token.

However after they've already used one it becomes invalid and so if they want to re-use it again, the user gets an error on the model:

```
Reset password token is invalid
```

This is from Devise itself. How can modify this message to be :

```
User reset password token already used
```

If I cannot change the message via some configuration, then is there a method that would allow me to check if the token is valid or not?

So that I can manually render this message in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Devise, but ActiveModel [error message](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message):

> `person.errors.full_message(:name, 'is invalid') # => "Name is invalid"`

And you can overwrite it in your locale file.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        reset_password_token: User reset password token
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            reset_password_token:
              invalid: already used
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the error messages in Devise by setting up your locale file (as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n))

You can find more on the use of locale files here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n

Comment: thanks for the tip @Zavitoski but looking at this link for English https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml I can only see `no_token` key, I do not see the key for when the token is invalid or where to look for one, do you know more details there?

Comment: It's not Devise message. It's Rails message

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change/customize devise error/flash messages...simply change the `devise.en.yml` file show below at `config/locals/devise.en.yml` location

```
######example
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      ##OLD => confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      confirmed: "Your are not a confirmed user.Kindly Confirm your Email Id"
```

Hope this helps ;)